# Complex Excel Transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I have to transpose some data into a completely different format and nothing seems to be working for me. I have tired Pivot Table, SUMIF, VLOOKUP and Concatenate but problem is not getting resolved.

**I have a data in the following format:**

```
CUSTOMER  Date         HOUR 1 HOUR 2 HOUR 3 HOUR 4.......HOUR 24
A         2019-02-20    1.5   1.7    1.9   1.10         1.78
A         2019-02-21    1.1   1.8    1.2   1.10         1.75
B         2019-02-20    1.0   1.2    1.4   1.29         1.73
B         2019-02-21    1.5   1.7    1.9   1.10         1.78
```

**I want this data to be transposed into the following format:**

```
DATE            CUSTOMER 

2019-02-20     A       B
HOUR 1        1.5      1.0 
HOUR 2        1.7      1.2
HOUR 3        1.9      1.4
HOUR 4        1.10     1.29
.
.
.
HOUR 24      1.78      1.73

2019-02-21   

HOUR 1       1.1       1.5  
HOUR 2       1.8       1.7
HOUR 3       1.2       1.9
HOUR 4       1.10      1.10
.
.
.
HOUR 24      1.75      1.78
```

Please advise how can i achieve this?

Comment: This isn't transposing, it's a completely different layout. Start by unpivoting the source data (PowerPivot can do that) so that you get 24 records per date/customer... and then it looks like you'll be able to pivot it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution than this ... but it seems to work
I haven't put much effort into cleaning up the code - still got Stops in it

The process is;
 .. Sort the data by Date
 .. Read it into an array .. re-arranging as we go
 .. Write the array to a different sheet

```
Sub ReArrangeMyData()
    ' First Sort the Raw Data by Date
      Application.Goto Reference:="rawdatarng"
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B11:B14"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A10:Z14")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
      End With
    ' Sorted

    Dim NewData(1 To 99, 1 To 26) As Variant

    ' Now parse each Row and Re-Arrange into new sheet ... via the NewData Array
      Dim SrcRng As Range, xRow As Range, tgtRow As Long, tgtCol As Long
      Dim FirstRow As String, dDate As String, dCust As String, i As Long, LastDate As String

      Set SrcRng = ActiveSheet.Range("RawDataRng")
      tgtRow = 0
      tgtCol = 0
      FirstRow = "Y"
      LastDate = "AnyInvlidRubbish"
      For Each xRow In SrcRng.Rows
         If FirstRow <> "Y" Then
            dDate = CStr(xRow.Cells(1, 2).Value)
            dCust = CStr(xRow.Cells(1, 1).Value)
            If dDate <> LastDate Then
               ' New Date = NewRow
               tgtRow = IIf(tgtRow = 0, 1, tgtRow + 26) ' Uses 1st Row on 1st Date then Jumps 26 Rows for other dates
               tgtCol = 0
               tgtCol = tgtCol + 1
               NewData(tgtRow, tgtCol) = dDate
               tgtCol = tgtCol + 1
               NewData(tgtRow, tgtCol) = dCust
               For i = 1 To 24
                  NewData(tgtRow + i, 1) = "Hour " & Right("00" & i, 2)
               Next i
            Else
               'tgtCol = tgtCol + 1
               'NewData(tgtRow, tgtCol) = dDate
               Stop
               tgtCol = tgtCol + 1
               NewData(tgtRow, tgtCol) = dCust
            End If

            For i = 1 To 24
               NewData(tgtRow + i, tgtCol) = CStr(xRow.Cells(1, 2 + i).Value)
            Next i
            LastDate = dDate
         End If
         FirstRow = "N"
      Next xRow
      Stop

      ' Finally Write the NewData Array into a different sheet
      For i = 1 To 99
         For J = 1 To 26
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(5 + i, J).Value = NewData(i, J)
         Next J
      Next i
      Stop
    ' Done
End Sub
```